# python 3.X urllib.request http error 416

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I wanted to get information from a site. Here's the simple code for it.

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.lamudi.com.ph/buy/?page=1&size=30')
html = response.read()
```

I'm getting a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular website do not want bots reading the content. The problem with `urllib.request.urlopen` is that it raises exception on 4xx or 5xx return codes making it difficult to see the actual response from the server. A better library would be [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

If you get the response, you would see:

> As you were browsing http://.... something about your browser made us think you were a bot.

You should check with them if you may use their information, but if this is for your own personal use, you may try changing the User Agent to one used by your browser.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'll look at the requests module as well as check with them about the information.